# Mixing types of Interpolation while Displaying Data

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, interpolation

We have a piece of in-house software for pulling data out of our system and displaying it. It can do this at the resolution of the data, aggregate it up to a lower resolution or down to a higher resolution. When we aggregate data to the lower resolution it is done using [nearest-neighbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) interpolation. We then display this on a time series chart using [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) between the each new data point.

Is mixing two types of interpolation a valid way of displaying data? Is it a bit contradictory to be using two types of interpolation together?